# XCode: Unsure on how to debug a objc_exception_throw on the Network layer

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, network-programming

Working on an iPhone App (using Xcode 7) I am getting the following exception but I have no ida where this is being called:

[image]

I have added an "All Exceptions" breakpoint, but it does not seem to suffice:

[image]

Any idea how I can debug this?

Comment: What's the error log in debugger?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Xcode compresses stacks to only show you user code, which is why you can't see all the stack frames between start_wqthread and objc_exception_throw.  You toggle that on and off with the first of the three little gadgets on the RHS of the Filter window at the bottom of the thread view.  That might help you some.

When stopped at the objc_exception_throw breakpoint, you can print out the exception message by doing:

```
(lldb) po $arg1
*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 10 beyond bounds for empty NSArray
```

That's an artificial example accessing beyond the range of an array.  If all goes well your message will be more illuminating.